# Wix: Uninstalling lauchnes installer instread

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to certify a desktop application for Windows 8.1 using Windows App Certification Kit 3.1.

Everything is fine with the exception of the uninstall.  I created the MSI file using Wix Toolkit 3.6.  When the application installs it creates an entry in ***Programs and Features*** as well as a ***shortcut for uninstalling***.

When I trigger the uninstall from either of these locations it works properly and all the files and registry entries get removed.

However, when the WACK launches the uninstall process, the MSI starts the installation process instead.

Is there a specific command from msiexec I need to test that WACK might be using to cause this?

I really do not understand why the Kit will launch the installer again.

Thank you,

Fernando

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and my solution.

The WACK calls the uninstall process using the Change option instead of Uninstall.  You can test this by going to ***Programs and Feature***s and clicking ***Change***.

Since my application does not support changing or repairing, I simply set ARPNOREPAIR and ARPNOMODIFY to "Yes" and now WACK only calls uninstall.

The other option is to offer the Change/Repair dialog on your setup project and have the Remove check-mark available.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Fernando